# how to share data across different micro apps in single-spa

Tags: reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend, single-spa

I understand how to pass custom props to different micro apps when using `single-spa` but I want to know how I can take the output of an api call form app1 and use it in app2. app1 is using `react-redux` and app2 will be using `react hooks`.

```
import {registerApplication, start} from 'single-spa'


registerApplication(
    'navBar',          // Name of this single-spa application
    () => import('./nav/navbar.app.js').then(module => module.navBar),
    () => true
)

registerApplication(
  'app1',          // Name of this single-spa application
  () => import('./root.app.js'),//loadingFunction, // Our loading function
  () => true, //activityFunction // Our activity function
)

registerApplication(
    'app2',          // Name of this single-spa application
    () => import('./app2/app2.app.js').then(module => module.app2),
    location =>
        location.pathname === '/app2' ||
        location.pathname.startsWith('/app2'),
    {
        some: 'value',
    }
)

start()
```

Or how can I call a root api call and share output across all micro apps. The above is my `index.js` which is called by `webpack`.

I am using single-spa version 4.x and webpack 4.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you share state in a micro-frontend scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60548251/how-do-you-share-state-in-a-micro-frontend-scenario)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sharing application state](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/faq/#how-can-i-share-application-state-between-applications) in single-spa is achieved using [a utility module pattern](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#utility-modules-styleguide-api-etc) to create a "service" that can be leveraged using [cross-microfrontend imports](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/recommended-setup/#cross-microfrontend-imports) to share cross all your microfrontends.

One example of this is using Rxjs to share login state cross multiple frontends, which you can find here: https://github.com/filoxo/single-spa-example-rxjs-shared-state Disclaimer: I authored this example.

Comment: great response and resources. thank you.